# Calling API from Power bi Desktop throws multiple errors (API KEY should be provided)

Tags: authentication, powerbi, restful-authentication

Im trying to call an API from power bi desktop using the web connector. I have the url which includes a query. I also have a Key which i will be using for connecting from power bi to that api.

I tried the below options:

1. Use Web connector --> Advanced --> In the headers, creates "Authorization" and provided the key, it failed with the error "A web API key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided"
2. M Query --> Web.Contents("https://api.xyz.com/page-metrics/get",[ApiKeyName="x_api_key"]), and passed the Key in the "Key" prompt using WEB API credential.
3. Use Web connector --> Advanced --> In the headers, create "ApiKeyName" and provided the key.

None of the above worked, while all the forums that i read through provided almost similar answers.

Am I doing something wrong here? or is there a different way of doing this? Appreciate if someone can throw some light. TIA.

My URL(test) looks like this : **https://api.testing.com/v3/external/reporting/sharing?endDate=2019-03-12&startDate=2019-03-02&metric=blend_sharing%67**